# Adding Button Actions - GetUIKit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, getuikit

I'm using the following GetUIKit: https://getuikit.com/

I want to use the UIKit and JS to do the following:

When a button named "Next" is pressed, the active item on an unordered list is changed to the subsequent item and that content appears. I would also like for a second button to appear, "Previous", if the active item is anything other than the first item in the UL.

Here is what I have so far:

```html
<ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill" uk-switcher>
    <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign-Up</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="uk-switcher uk-margin">
    <li>Welcome!</li>
    <li>Here is how you can get involved!</li>
    <li>Fill out the following form to be added to our contact list!</li>
</ul>

<button class="uk-button uk-button-default">Previous</button>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-default">Next</button>
```

UIKit provides navigation from the subnavs. In other words, I can click on those and it will pull up the corresponding item from the subsequent UL.

My issue is how I do this using a Next and Previous button. Are buttons the best choice? If so, using JS, what is the best way to go about manipulating the HTML/CSS to change what appears based on user's selection of "Next" or "Previous"?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use "Tab" in Uikit, Just use that tabbing name as Next/Prev

```
    <ul uk-tab>
        <li class="uk-active"><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li class="uk-disabled"><a></a></li>
    </ul>
```